# Teamcity build configuration trigger by another repo

Tags: git, teamcity, cocoapods, build-automation

I have an app git repo and a framework git repo.

App uses the framework thru cocoapods.

I have a teamcity project that does the CI stuff for the app.

So when the Framework Repo master branch is updated (someone commits something to master branch on framework repo)
 I'd like my App project on teamcity CI to trigger an action.

According to here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Build+Triggers I have to have 2 VCS roots for the same build configuration?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project settings, create a vcs root there.
Then go to your build configuration settings, vcs roots tab, and attach a second root to the build configuration

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this, you can add a successful build complete trigger on app the build which will listen to framework repo. So, whenever framework build finishes, app build will get triggered.

Read [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Finish+Build+Trigger)..